# Java type mismatch when calling interface with it's own return type?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I've been banging my head on this problem for the last few days and searching everything I could think of to no avail.

I have a class interacting with another through an interface. I'm getting some type mismatch errors with code that seems simple enough to me.

```
public class FooBar {
  Foo<? extends Bar> X = new Y();

  public void test(){
    if X.isA(X.B()){
       //do something; type mismatch here
    }

  }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface Foo<T extends Bar> {
  public T B();
  public boolean isA(T t);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class Y implements Foo<T extends Bar> {
  public int B(){
    return 5;
  }

  public boolean isA(int num){
    int A = 10;
    return (A == num) ? true : false;

}
```

My point of issue is the method test(). I'm getting a number through the interface, then testing it with the same instance of the implementation class, but this is giving me a capture/type mismatch error.

> CAP#1 extends Bar from capture of ? extends Bar
>
> CAP#2 extends Bar from capture of ? extends Bar

I've tried a number of things that I've found in my searches, but none of them have worked. Generics and interfaces are new to me and I'm still learning them. Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't `isA` take `T` instead of `int` ? Or signature of the class changed to `public class Y implements Foo<Integer>`

Comment: As a side note `return (A == num) ? true : false;` could simply be `return A == num;`

Comment: Where is the Bar class?

Comment: Your `X` is a consumer, so it should be a `Foo<? super Bar>`, if wildcards are even necessary at all. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2891664

Comment: One item that is incorrect is you have an interface `Foo<T extends Bar>`. Then you have the concrete class `Y implements Foo<T extends Bar>` For Y, the 'T' is of type int, which is invalid. 'T' must not be a primitive and must be a class that extends Bar.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your classes (and added the missing Bar class for clarity). 
You can now run the `FooBar.main()` method and get the results you expect:

```
public class FooBar {
    Foo x = new Y();

    public void test(){
        if(x.isA(x.B())){
            System.out.println("x.isA!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        FooBar fb = new FooBar();
        fb.test();
    }
}

public interface Foo<T extends Bar> {
    T B();
    boolean isA(T t);
}

public class Bar {}

public class ExtendsBar extends Bar {

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Yes I extend Bar";
    }
}

public class Y implements Foo<ExtendsBar> {
    public ExtendsBar B() {
        return new ExtendsBar();
    }

    public boolean isA(ExtendsBar num) {
        return (num instanceof Bar);
    }
}
```